# CodeIgniter encryption library check if exists

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I have a project where a customer buys some "tokens" which can be redeemed elsewhere. These tokens are essentially like gift cards and have a random ID associated with them.

Once the payment has cleared, there is a manual process where we upload a list of the codes that they purchased.

I am using CodeIgniters `encryption` library to encode them for storage in the database.

`$this->encryption->encrypt($data['Pin'])`

Since there is some manual intervention (that I am trying to move away from), I want to ensure the a code is never uploaded that has been uploaded in the past (ie don't want to give customer B the same code customer A had).

What would be the best way to make sure this code code doesn't exist in the database already during the upload process?

As a test, I uploaded the same 5 pins multiple times and their storage in the DB is always different (good thing) but I am unable to just do a simple compare.

The only thing I can think of, which I don't like, creating a function that loops over each of the pins currently stored, decodes them, and compares it prior to upload. Just didn't want to have a method that essentially retrieved a full list of this data in one shot.

What have I got myself into here?

Comment: This is what hashing functions are for. Store a hash of the unencrypted code, and make sure you index it.

Comment: Why are you encrypting them at all?  What do you want to achieve by doing so?

Comment: @LukePark - I don't like the thought of a database full of plain text gift card codes is all?

Comment: Bear in mind that if your application can decode what you've stored, then so can an attacker that's breached your application.

Comment: @Sammitch - Suggestions on a better approach? I need to be able to deliver this code to the end user. I assume that the application needs to know how to decode it to provide them with the end result?

Comment: In cases like this, skip the encryption and focus on making your application solid.

Comment: Yes, this is pointless encryption unless the key is derived from the users password.